# Показ определённой страницы, в зависимости от условия

Tags: wordpress, ajax

Подскажите, на сайте используется сервис fingerprint.
При загрузке страницы по ajax отправляется результат этого сервиса fingerprint на бэкенд и нужно в зависимости от полученного результата показать определённую страницу, вообще не связанную с wordpress, допустим страница написанная на php в файле somepage.php, который лежит где-то в корне сайта.

```
**js**
let fpPromise = import('https://fpjscdn.net/v3/fasdfasdfsa')
        .then(FingerprintJS => FingerprintJS.load())

    // Analyze the visitor when necessary.
    fpPromise
        .then(fp => fp.get())
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result.requestId, result.visitorId);

            fetch(ajaxurl, {
                method: "POST",
                body: {result.requestId, action: 'get_page_content'},
            })
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(response => {
                    let resp = JSON.parse(response);
                    if (resp.page) {
                        //здесь сработало условие тогда нужно полностью заменить всю страницу (html head body)
                    }
                });
        })

**php**
add_action('wp_ajax_get_page_content', 'get_page_content');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_page_content', 'get_page_content');
function get_page_content()
{
    $requestId = !empty($_POST['requestId'])? sanitize_text_field($_POST['requestId']) : '';

    // Create a new Configuration instance with your Fingerprint Pro Server API Key and your Fingerprint Pro Server API Region.
    $config = Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration(FPJS_API_SECRET, Configuration::REGION_EUROPE);
    $client = new FingerprintApi(
        new Client(),
        $config
    );

    // Get an event with a given requestId
    try {
        // Fetch the event with a given requestId
        $response = $client->getEvent($requestId);
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }

    if (!empty($response) && $response->какое-то условие == true) {
        ob_start();
        include('/somepage.php');
        wp_send_json(['page'=>ob_get_clean()]);
    }
}
```

т.е. если сработало какое-то условие, то нужно показать somepage.php, иначе обычная загрузка wordpress.
Как это правильно сделать? В ответе по ajax нужно делать редирект на somepage.php?
Или нужно подменять контент данной страницы из возвращённого ответа по ajax с помощью js без перезагрузки?

**PS**

Comment: Составь нормально текст вопроса. Эту простыню невозможно читать.

Comment: @SeVlad Интересует этот участок в ajax-запросе //здесь сработало условие тогда нужно полностью заменить всю страницу (html head body)

Comment: Разделение простыни кодом не сделало её читабельной.

Comment: По условию надо делать wp_safe_redirect https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_safe_redirect